# Using shared memory between two programs

Tags: c, fork, shared-memory, pid

I'm having some issues with shared memory. I want to pass a value into shared memory from program a that will be messed with and put back into that shared memory from program b, that program one can then read. As of now I can only get it to show me the value that I put in. I don't know if its the timing that needs to be corrected between reading from the shared memory and writing to it or if I have the wrong idea in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

When I run the programs, the command line looks like: ./a 2 3 4 ./b

It then asks for a value: 3

output: 3

Its supposed to raise 3 to some powers and multiply by those coefficients in the command line.

Program a:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int ac, char** a)
{
  key_t key=22;
  int size=1, shmflg=0;
  int id=0,ok=0,i=0, count=0;
  int *shmptr;
  int *pid;
  int status;
  double sum, value;
  char shmstr[10];
  char istr[10];   /* index for shared memory*/
  char arg1[10];
  char arg2[10];
  char power[10];

  count =(ac-2);
  size = count*sizeof(int);
  pid = (int*) malloc(size);
  shmflg = IPC_CREAT | SHM_R | SHM_W;
  id=shmget(key,size,shmflg);
  printf("%d get shmget\n",id);
  sprintf(shmstr, "%d",id);
  shmptr = shmat(id,0,0);
  for (i=0; (i < count); i=i+1){
     shmptr[i]=0;
  }  
  for (i=0; (i < count); i=i+1){
    if ((pid[i]=fork()) == 0) {
      sprintf(istr, "%d",ok);
      sprintf(power, "%d",((ac-2)-i));
      execlp(a[(ac-1)], a[(ac-1)], shmstr, istr,a[i+1],power, NULL);
    }
  }

/* /////////////////////////////////// I believe this is were the issue lies.*/
  printf("value?");
  scanf("%lf",&value);
  while(value!=0){
    sum=1;
    shmptr[ok]=value;``
    sum=shmptr[(ok+1)];
    printf("and the value is now %f \n", sum);
    printf("value?\n");
    scanf("%lf",&value);
  }

  for (i=0; (i < count); i=i+1){
      ok=waitpid(pid[i],&status,0);
      printf("%d wait on %d ok\n",ok, i);
    }

  ok=shmdt(shmptr);
  ok = shmctl(id,IPC_RMID,0);

}
```

Program b:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>


int main(int ac, char** a)
{
  int id=0,ok=0, i=0, j=0, power;
  int *shmptr;
  double x, mult, mycontrib, total;
  id = atoi(a[1]);
  i = atoi(a[2]);
  mult=atof(a[3]);
  power=atoi(a[4]);
  shmptr = shmat(id,0,0);
  x=shmptr[i];
  printf("child %d shmptr index value %d\n",i,shmptr[i]);
  while(x!=0){
    mycontrib=1;
    for(j=0;(j<power);j=j+1){
      mycontrib=mycontrib*x;
    }

    total=total+(mycontrib*mult);
    shmptr[i]=total;
  }
   ok=shmdt(shmptr);
   printf("%d child detach ok\n",ok);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need better synchronization between program A and program B. I.e. program B need to know, definitively, when program A has completed placing the input in SHM. For example, after placing the input, program A might send a signal to program B. Or, you can use semaphores.

Also, do not assume that integer read/write are atomic.

```
shmptr[ok]=value;  // A

x=shmptr[i];       // B
```

Comment: Would a wait statement be appropriate? Wait until the value of shmptr[ok]!=value that was entered?

Comment: `wait()` system calls are used to wait for state changes in a child of the calling process. But, as I understand this problem, A and B are independent processes, neither is child of the other.

Comment: Oh okay, what about a loop that until the value is no longer the same?while(value==shmptr[ok]){};?

Comment: Again, do not assume that read/writes are atomic. Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science) You need proper synchronizations between A and B. Without that, they may be working correctly sometimes, but that is pure chance, not guaranteed. No matter what, you want your programs to be guaranteed to work, won't you?